# Check Oracle Database connectivity from Application server

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-connection, windows-server, application-server

We have Oracle Database DB1 hosted on Unix Server and Application on Windows server 2012.

How Do I check whether Application server is having connectivity from Oracle database DB1?

Can someone pls help?

Answer (score 0):

Did you looked at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/connect.htm#NETAG383 ?

What is exactly going wrong?

Comment: If this is an answer, you should add more content from the link.

Comment: No, It did not help.

I am trying to do TNSPING from Windows server(App server)  but I am getting error - the command is not recognized.